# 404 page not found error with pagination and permalinks on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

i have created a custom post type in wordpress by adding the following to my custom themes function.php

```
function oil_paintings_init() {
$args = array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'oil-paintings' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'oil-painting' ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'oil-painting'),
  ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'revisions',
        'page-attributes',)
    );
register_post_type( 'oil-paintings', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'oil_paintings_init' );
```

I have created a custom page template which loops and displays the posts from the custom post type i have added above . I want to show 5 posts at a time and rest by next and previous links on the page. This is the code which i have used:

```
<?php
  $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged'))? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args =array(
         'post_type'=>'oil-paintings',
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
         'nopaging' => false, 
          'paged' => $currentPage, 

    );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if($wp_query->have_posts()): while($wp_query->have_posts()) :    $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="columns">
    <img src="<?php the_field('image1'); ?>" alt="" />
    <a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
 next_posts_link("next");
 previous_posts_link("prev");
 endif; 
 wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The problem i am facing is when i enable permalinks in my wordpress to

```
'http://www.domainname.com/%postname%/' -->this does not work
```

the next and previous posts link stop working and i get a page not found error. everything works ok if my permalinks is set to plain

```
'http://www.domainname.com/?p=123' --> this works
```

any help in this regard is aprreciated.
Thanks

OK i figured out where i was going wrong. Moving the rewrite out of the labels array solved it for me. Here is the working code in functions.php

```
 function oil_paintings_init() {
$args = array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'oil-paintings' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'oil-painting' )
  ),
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'oil-painting'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'revisions',
        'page-attributes',)
    );
register_post_type( 'oil-paintings', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'oil_paintings_init' );
```

Comment: why two slashes (`//`) in permalink?

Comment: can you provide an example of a page that is 404 for you (the path after the domain)? My guess is whatever post name you are using may contain special characters which would cause the page to fail. you may need to use the esc_url()

Comment: this is what i get http://www.domain.com/oil-paintings/page/2/

Comment: did you update your `.htaccess` file? - (http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) can you confirm it? i.e. you need to make sure you have permissions to modify the file

Comment: Yes, the .hhtacces file is updated

Comment: Figured out what i was doing wrong. See my post for the solution. Thanks everyone for the help